# In C finding specific words

Tags: c, search

I am trying to write a program in C in which I have to take input an another java file and find a specific word like `class`.

How can i do this?

Comment: Sure you can. If you show us what you tried and what went wrong, we might be able to help...

Comment: The [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) function (declared in `<string.h>`) ( or POSIX's [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html), declared in `<strings.h>` ) might be useful :)

Comment: Please expand your question and demonstrate what you've tried already. The Stack Overflow community is here to help, but you can't expect it to write all of your code. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
. open the file as 'text' for reading
. while end-of-file not reached
.   read next line
.   parse/analyze line
.   if line contains "class"
.     here you got the specific word
. close the file
```